# ¿Cómo identificar si un parámetro pasado por método POST es null o vacío?

Tags: c#, asp.net, aplicación-web

Envío varios parámetros por un método POST y antes de asignarlos quisiera saber si alguno es null o vacío.

Este es mi código:

```
System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection nameValue = Request.Form;
if (nameValue.Count > 0)
{
    // Aquí reccorrer la colección para identificar si algún item es null o vacio
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El tema es que si estas iterando por las key existentes ninguna sera null, porque solo recorres las que llegan en el POST y tienen un valor

```
foreach(string key in Request.Form) 
{
   string valor = Request.Form[key]; 
}
```

el null aplica cuando quieres tomar una key especifica y esta puede que no existe en la coleccion.

Comment: Por ejemplo cuando hago click en un form y un <input type="text" /> esta vacio ??

Comment: ok pero seria el contenido el que llega vacio, o sea en el ejemplo seria la variable "valor" la que debes validar

Answer (score 2):

Comprobar mediante `!= null` y que el length sea mayor a `0`
O la Mejor forma recurrir al Método [IsNullOrEmpty](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-PE/library/system.string.isnullorempty(v=vs.110).aspx) que realiza dicha verificación con una sola instrucción.

```
if(Request.QueryString["nameparam"]!=null || 
Convert.ToString(Request.QueryString["nameparam"]).Length> 0){...}
// o También así
if(IsNullOrEmpty(Convert.ToString(Request.QueryString["nameparam"])){...}
```

Comment: Gracias ,pero aún no había terminado de completar mi respuesta :)

Comment: Oops! Perdón. Se ve bien después de la edición

Comment: Request.QueryString es para metodo get ..si no me equivoco....deberia ser con Request:Form

Answer (score 2):

Podrías utilizar el método [IsNullOrEmpty](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-ES/library/system.string.isnullorempty(v=vs.110).aspx) de C#, que comprobará si el parámetro pasado es NULL o está vacío y devolverá `true` si lo es, o `false` si no lo es (es decir, si es `false` entonces tiene datos).

Así podrías hacer algo como:

```
string valor = Request.Form["parametro"];
if (! String.IsNullOrEmpty(valor)) {
    // operaciones con el valor
}
```

Answer (score -1):

asi quedo el codigo

```
 foreach (string key in Request.Form)
    {
       if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(key))
            {
              // Aqui Mi codigo
            }
    }
```

Comment: pero la key nunca sera nula o vacia, porque recorres las existentes, el if esta de mas

Comment: yo tengo un formulario y si dejo un textbox vacio me sale error...quiero recorrer para si existe uno vacio o null salirme de la funcion...